# "expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char' " - palindrom + reverse

Tags: c, string, char, palindrome

Right now this program succesfully reverses a word typed in by the keyboard. But I want to "save" the word in the pointer before I reverse it, so I can compare both, the reversed one and the "original", and check if they are palindromes. I don't have much experience yet and there might be more errors than I know of, but I can't find a solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char s[])
{
    int c,i,j;
    for(i=0, j=strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--)
    {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }

}

void Palindromcheck(char u[], char g[])
{
    if(u == g)
    {
        printf("Word \"%s\" is a palindrom\n", g);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Word \"%s\" is not a Palindrom\n", g);
    }
}
int main()
{
    char c[30];
    printf("Please enter a value \n");
    scanf("%s", c);
    char *ptr1 = c;
    printf("String: %s\n", c);
    reverse(c);
    printf("%s\n", c);
    Palindromcheck(c, *ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

I get two warnings saying:

> expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char'

at the function `palindromcheck` itself, such as:

> passing argument 2 of 'palindromcheck' makes pointer from integer without a 
>        cast [-Wint-conversion]

at the function call.

Appreciate any help:)

Comment: `Palindromcheck(c, ptr1);` ? The * declares it as a pointer, but when you prefix it with a star later that means dereference.

Comment: Note that `if(u == g)` will compare the positions of the pointers, not the contents of the arrays. Also passing in `char[]` doesn't pass the length, just the start pointer, so you'll need to pass the length in too if you want to use that for comparison.

Comment: ... and you should `strdup` the string that you're going to reverse. As it stands ptr1 is an alias of the c buffer, and so when you reverse it in place you're also reversing c. You'll need to take a copy of it (and ideally free() the copy afterwards)

Comment: It would appear that argument 2 of Palindromcheck makes a pointer from integer without a cast. The compiler expected char* but the argument is of type char. How much clearer does the compiler message need to be?

Comment: @Lundin Since I am new to programming and not native to the english language,  it can be hard to understand what exactly is needed to solve a problem, even if it sounds trivial to you.

Answer (score 4):

Toy need to change this

```
Palindromcheck(c, *ptr1);
```

to this

```
Palindromcheck(c, ptr1);
```

Function expects pointer to `char`, as parameter is `char g[]`, and you are trying to pass just `char` value.